# Objective-c turn off class / code block at runtime if framework doesn't exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm creating a framework which could contain multiple third party frameworks. The other third party frameworks are installed via cocoapods. Is it possible to check in my framework when the example app compiles if a certain third party framework exists, and if not turn off that part of the code or class so no errors will be thrown? When the framework does exist I want to turn on the code or class so the class or code can be used.

I tried using some methods (see code) in my own created cocoapods but it didn't really work.

```
__has_include('class.h')

Class klass = NSClassFromString(@"class.h");
return klass != nil;
```

Basically the code above always returns false or doesn't include class.h even when a third party framework is installed through cocoapods.

Answer (score 0):

How do you configure your framework on wether to install a third party lib or not?

If you are using several targets for your framework that each contain a different set of thirdparty frameworks installed through cocoapods, you could easily use 'Preprocessor Macros' (ObjC) or 'Other Swift Flags' (Swift).

You can set them in your frameworks Build settings, depending on the libraries used in that target, and in your code check them with #ifdef (ObjC) or #if (swift)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply! So I'm using cocoapods to install the other frameworks.

Comment: Okay, but when you say you have different sets of third party libs in the framework, how do you change that? do you just edit the Podfile and rund `pod install` again?

Comment: The idea is that we make it easier for clients to communicate with the third party frameworks we're going to use (can't mention names unfortunately) and stuff that comes with those (like API calls).
Let's call our framework AwesomeSDK, lets say we have Client A who wants to have the AwesomeSDK + Framework A and Framework B and Client B uses the AwesomeSDK but only with FrameWork A I want to remove / disable the code from Framework B because obviously it's not there. All the third party frameworks will be installed via cocoapods in their own project so our framework + framework A + framework b

Answer (score 0):

Use the Objective C or Swift symbol name of the class in the call to `NSClassFromString` - not the header file name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample does not check the result of `__has_include` so the following code will be executed regardless, and it doesn't actually do an `#include` at all. You use `__has_include` inside an `#if` to guard an `#include` and any associated code, for example:

```
#if __has_include("class.h")
// code if include file is present
#include "class.h"
... // any other code
#else
... // code if include file is not present
#endif
```

For further details see [C preprocessor docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/_005f_005fhas_005finclude.html). HTH